# Need help finding an overlap between two strings, and returning a number which is how much the strings overlap

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that takes two strings, and if they have an overlap then return a number which is how much they overlap. example:

the function is named

```
findLargestOverlap(target, candidate)
```

and if i were to enter bbbbbabc as the target and abcbbbba as the candidate is should return 3 becuase that is how much they overlap. i have been working on this for about 3 hours and cant find anything that works. any help would be great

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: Do you have the code you have worked on? Can you share that so we can see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're trying to find how much the end of target overlaps with the beginning of candidate:

```
def findLargestOverlap(target, candidate):
    # calculates how much the end of target overlaps with the beginning of candidate

    # identify locations in target that are equal to the first letter of candidate
    # these locations are the only possible start locations of a overlap
    poss_starts = []
    for i in range(len(target)-1,0-1,-1):
        # print(i)
        if target[i] == candidate[0]:
            poss_starts.append(i)

    # starting from the beginning of target, test each poss_start as a match
    # start from the beginning so that if there are
    # two overlapping sections due to repeats, it returns the longer
    for poss_start in reversed(poss_starts):
        poss_length = len(target) - poss_start
        if target[poss_start:] == candidate[:poss_length]:
            return poss_length

    return 0


target = 'bbbbbabc'
candidate = 'abcbbbba'
print(findLargestOverlap(target, candidate))
# >> 3
print(findLargestOverlap(candidate, target))
# >> 0

target = 'abcbbbbba'
candidate = 'bbbbbabc'
print(findLargestOverlap(target, candidate))
# >> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve this problem. Let me give you two solutions:

## Solution 1:

Break the candidate string into multiple strings where each string is 1 more than the previous one.  For candidate string, you go from left to right. In your example, candidate string `'abcbbbba'` can be broken down into `a`, `ab`, `abc`,  `abcb`, `abcbb`, `abcbbb`, `abcbbbb`, `abcbbbba`.

Similarly break the target string into smaller bits. The target string has to be broken down from right to left.

Now check if the longest broken string matches between candidate and target. If it does, then the length of that string is the number of strings that match.

Here's the code that does the second solution.

```
target    = 'bbbbbabc'
candidate = 'abcbbbba'
x = [candidate[:i+1] for i in range(len(candidate))]
y = [target[-len(a):] for a in x]
x.reverse()
y.reverse()

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i]==y[i]:
        print('There are',len(x[i]),'items matching')
        break
else:
    print('There are no items matching')
```

In python, the for loop can have an else statement. The else statement will be executed if the for loop completed successfully without breaking. If the for loop triggered a break, else is not invoked.

The output for:

```
candidate = 'abcbbbba'
target = 'bbbbbabc'
```

results in:

```
There are 3 items matching
```

The output for:

```
candidate = 'abcbbbba'
target = 'bbbbbaac'
```

results in:

```
There are no items matching
```

## Solution 2:

Move from left to right on `candidate` value. Move from right to left on `target` value. When you find a match, the flag it as a match and continue. If the immediate next item is not a match, then stop.

```
target    = 'bbbbbabc'
candidate = 'abcbbbba'

matches=False
i=1
while True:
    a = len(candidate[:i])
    if candidate[:i]==target[-a:]:
        matches=True
    elif matches:
        break

    i+=1
    if i > len(candidate) or i > len(target):
        break

if matches:
    print('There are',i-1,'matching items')
else:
    print('There are no matching items')
```

The output for this is the same as above:

```
candidate = 'abcbbbba'
target = 'bbbbbabc'
```

results in:

```
There are 3 items matching
```

The output for:

```
candidate = 'abcbbbba'
target = 'bbbbbaac'
```

results in:

```
There are no items matching
```